# How to locate jdk in visual studio for Xamarin?

Tags: android, xamarin.android, java-6

I try to programing in visual studio for android.
I install SDK , JDK ,Xamarin .Now I want set path of jdk to the visual studio but vs get message that :

> Cannot find Java Development Kit files in specified path:
>
> C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.6.0_07\bin

I set this path for `Path` and `Home_java` variable on the Enviroment Variable  in SystemAdvanceSetting.
I use `where javac` in cmd but it can not find java path.

How to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Xamarin 4.1.2.18 and earlier [doesn't currently support a 64-bit JDK](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/getting_started/installation/windows/manual_installation/#Requirements).  You should install a 32-bit version of JDK 1.7u79, which Xamarin will be able to detect.  You can see which JDK Xamarin is using by clicking the Visual Studio menu Tools > Xamarin. You will see the listed JDK and Android SDK directories.

> Xamarin.Android 4.1.2.18 and earlier also requires that a **32-bit** Java JDK 7 (1.7) be
>   installed. Later versions of the JDK can also be installed alongside
>   JDK 7, if required by your machine.

You can use a 64-bit JDK 8 installation with the newer Xamarin 4.2 and later.

Comment: Xamarin needs 1.7 32bit.

Comment: I install java version 1.7 and solved.Thank you for answering :)

Comment: NOTE: To avoid confusion for future readers, the original question shows a path to a **JRE**.  Don't download one of those, and expect to have enough to build Xamarin.Android apps. This answer is saying to get the **JDK** 1.7.  And the path used should be to the jdk folder, NOT the jre folder.  E.g. `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_71` (or whatever build the final jdk 1.7 is)

Comment: Not anymore. They do support 64-bit JDK at least with JDK 1.8. That's my setup and it works. See https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/platform_features/introduction-to-nougat/#sdk item #4

Answer (score 1):

Your JDK path must point to `C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.6.0_07`, not to the `bin` directory.

Update your JAVA_HOME environment variable and try again.

Comment: Are you getting the exact same message?

Comment: Find your JDK folder, not the JRE.  Depending if you installed 32 or 64 bit version, look in C:\Program Files\Java\ or C:\Program Files(x86)\Java\ once you've found the correct path, point Xamarin to it.